# How to run cronjob with a user other than root on solaris server

Tags: unix, command, cron

I found many similar questions on internet but no one could resolve my problem..I am working on Solaris 5.10 machine.. Here Inside a shell script a customized command is being run like below.

```
palf -f ${basePath}/palf_file.DAT -e ${basePath}/LOG/palf_file.log
```

This command only runs while logged in as "palf" user. Now this script & subsequently this command is running perfectly from command prompt. But crontab is not able run this command.
I tried few things.. I changed the entry of my crontab file like below which could not even run the script.

```
40 15 * * * palf bash /opt/bin/scripts/script.sh
```

Then I tried to edit a cronfile as "palf" user by using the below command but it gave me `"invalid options"` error.

```
crontab -u palf -e
```

I also tried

```
crontab -e palf
```

It opened a crontab file but it was same as the root's crontab file not the user's specific
Nothing worked for me. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

```
palf -f ${basePath}/palf_file.DAT -e ${basePath}/LOG/palf_file.log
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    logger "palf command failed. Please check..." 1
else
    logger "palf command successfully executed..." 0
fi
```

This is how I am checking the status of palf command.. and it prints "palf command failed. Please check..." using logger function every time it runs using cronjob.

Comment: "*But crontab is not able run this command.*" -- How did it fail?

Comment: It doesn't give any kind of error message.. Doesn't even create "palf_file.log".. Only value of "$?" comes out to be "1" after that command..

Comment: If the `crontab` command sets `$?` to `1`, that means the crontab command itself failed. I don't know why it didn't print an error message.

Comment: I have added in the original question, how I am using "$?" with the command. thanks

Comment: I have to run this command at any cost.. If I make PW less connection to same server using palf id & run  ssh root@palf_server_ip "palf -f ${basePath}/palf_file.DAT -e ${basePath}/LOG/palf_file.log" will it work?